# how to serve a file within the spray framework (type mismatch getFromFile)?

Tags: scala, spray

This is probably a simple question, but I am new to Scala (and java too). I am trying to implement a spray file server. Everything works when I am returning the Hello-string, but when trying to serve a file with getFromFile I get:

```
Error:(16, 24) type mismatch;
found   : spray.routing.Route
(which expands to)  spray.routing.RequestContext => Unit
 required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
        getFromFile("build.sbt")
                   ^
                        ^
```

How should I resolve this error?

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp

object Main extends SimpleRoutingApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
    startServer(interface="localhost", port = 8080) {
        path("File") {
          complete {
            "Hello"
            //getFromFile("build.sbt")
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getFromFile automatically completes the request, so remove the complete and try like it is below. And do make sure your working directory is set such that build.sbt is in the current directory

```
object Main extends SimpleRoutingApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
    startServer(interface="localhost", port = 8080) {
        path("File") {
            getFromFile("build.sbt")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked (I checked that build.sbt was in the directory).

Answer (score 1):

"build.sbt" is not a directory, it is a file, you have to use a folder destination. e.g. `getFromDirectory("myfiles")` since `myfiles` exists at `src/main/resources/myfiles`.
If you want to serve just one file like `index.html` use `getFromFile("index.html")` since thist file exists at "src/main/resources/index.html"

[getFromDirectory docs api](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/file-and-resource-directives/getFromDirectory/)

regards.

Comment: thanks, you are right. I just tried several things. I will edit it. However, the type problem remains.

Comment: uhmmm sorry I didn't see the type error... try importing this `import spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller` @stian